# error C2544: expected ')' for operator '()'

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I am getting following error.

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void*> >  PropInfoType;
#define REGISTER_FUNCTOR(type, func) \
  template <typename OWNER> \
  struct writeCharFunctor { \
    void operator(PropInfoType::iterator& it)() { \
    } \
  };

  REGISTER_FUNCTOR(char,writeChar);
```

MSDN just saying that this is due to `macro expansion`

If I change `void operator(PropInfoType::iterator& it)()` to `void operator()()` it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably should contain

```
 void operator () (PropInfoType::iterator& it) { \
```

because the `operator` keyword should be followed by the operator itself.